# How to create custom Calendar and update date/time with AlarmManager in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Like Digital clock or Analog Clock, Do we have anything to display the date inside of our application. This should change the date on every day which is similar to digital clock changes time for every second.

If there is no controller is available then how can we display the date inside of our app. And this should change whenever the mobile date changes.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score -1):

You may need timer for this  as follows ,

1. Initialize Timer,TimerTask and handler

   ```
   Timer timer;
   TimerTask timerTask;
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
   ```
2. Start timer within OnResume() and will repeat once a minute

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 60000); 
   }
   ```
3. Display the time

   ```
   public void setUpTimer() 
   {   
   timerTask = new TimerTask() 
   {
       public void run() 
       {
           handler.post(new Runnable() 
           {
               public void run() 
               {

               SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(""EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"");
               String date = sdf.format(new Date()); 
               textView.setText(date);
               }
           });
       }
   };
   }
   ```

Comment: I clearly mentioned that Digital Clock. Like that I want to display the date like Jan 22, Feb 13 and all. I don't want any tutorial link.

Comment: you looking for a widget or a code in order to show the date ?

Comment: Not an widget. Jan 22, 12.30 PM ET. I want to display like this in text view and it will be keep on running with time or date. Hope you are getting my point.

Comment: No Need Timer. Totally 3 text view. 1st Text View - Get the mobile date info then set the alarm to trigger at 12 o clock to update the date on next day.  2nd Text View - I thought of using Digital Clock for time alone. 3rd Text view - Get the Mobile Time Zone. I hope this would be the simpler solution than what u shared. Please share me your suggestion too.

Comment: Not simple as it look , In such case, you need AlarmManager, refere this https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Yes Already I have scheduled an alarm at night 12 o clock daily. Not separately creating for this feature. So just reusing the same alarm to update the date. Hope this will solve.